# Why doesn't getchar() receive any input?

Tags: c, arrays, string, fgets, getchar

I made a program to see what your name is, if you were a male or female, how old you are, and if I should call you as Mrs, Ms, Mr, or just by your full name depending on the previous conditions. When I pick my gender as female and enter a first name, last name, and a age that's over or equal to 20 I ask if that person is married, however for whatever reason the program skips over the `getchar`, and just finishes the program.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char gender;
    char fName[15]; 
    char lName[15];
    char mar;
    char str[] = "Then I shall call you";
    int age = 0;

    printf("What is your gender (M or F): ");
    gender = getchar();

    printf("First name: ");
    scanf("%s", fName);
    //fgets(fName, 16, stdin);
    //fName[strcspn(fName, "\n")] = 0;

    printf("Last name: ");
    scanf("%s", lName);
    //fgets(lName, 16, stdin);
    //lName[strcspn(lName, "\n")] = 0;

    printf("Age: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);

    puts("");

    if(gender == 'F' || gender == 'f')
    {
        if(age >= 20)
        {   
            printf("Are you married, %s (y or n)?: ", fName);

            //scanf("%c", &mar);
            mar=getchar();

            printf("%c\n", mar); 

            if(mar == 'Y' || mar == 'y')
                printf("%s Mrs. %s.\n", str, lName);

            else if(mar == 'n' && age >= 20|| mar == 'N' && age >= 20)
                printf("%s Ms. %s.\n", str, lName);
        }

        else
            printf("%s %s %s.\n", str, fName, lName);
    }

    else if(gender == 'M' || gender == 'm')
    {
        if(age >= 20)
            printf("%s Mr. %s.\n", str, lName);

        else
            printf("%s %s %s.\n", str, fName,lName);
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
What is your gender (M or F): F
First name: Jane
Last name: Doe
Age: 25

Are you married, Jane (y or n)?:
```

I also have another question as to when I used `fgets` instead of `scanf` to read the string. As I heard to typically stay away from `scanf` when reading strings I tried `fgets` but the output wasn't as I wanted it to be.

Here is the output when I used `fgets` instead of `scanf`:

```
What is your gender (M or F): M 
First name: Last name: Joe
Age: 23

Then I shall call you Mr. Joe.
```

The output should be as it was when I used the `scanf` so that The last name is underneath the first name.

Comment: Your problems come from mixing single character `getchar()` with multi-char input in `scanf` or `fgets`. When you press Enter, that produces a character as well, which you have to handle.

Comment: Use either `scanf(" %c", &mar);` or `getchar(); mar=getchar()`. The problem is because of the newline character left over by the previous scanf.

Comment: when calling the system function: `scanf()`,  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using a input/format string that does not automatically skip over white space, insert a space into the format string before the (for instance) %s, so any leading white space is automatically consumed.  3) when using the format `%s` always use the max length modifier (which needs to be 1 less than the actual input buffer length) I.E. `%14s` for a 15 char input buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why doesn't `getchar()` receive any input?

Code has 2 problems:

1) It got the left-over `'\n'` from the previous line, use `scanf(" %c", &mar);` (note space) or better yet, replace all input with `fgets()`

2) It did not report unexpected input. Code should detect and report unexpected input and handle all possible paths of logic.  Example:

```
    {   
        printf("Are you married, %s (y or n)?: ", fName);
        mar=getchar();
        printf("%c\n", mar); 
        if(mar == 'Y' || mar == 'y')
            printf("%s Mrs. %s.\n", str, lName);
        else if(mar == 'N' || mar == 'n') {
           if (age >= 20)
             printf("%s Ms. %s.\n", str, lName);
           else 
             printf("%s ??? %s.\n", str, lName);
        }
        else { 
          printf("Unexpected input char:'%c' code:%d\n", mar, mar);
        }  
    }
```

Comment: I used the `scanf(" %c", &mar);` but I would rather use the `fgets` due to it being a better habit, but when I try to do it it gives me warnings, saying that its a pointer from a integer, when clearly its a cast, is there any way to do this correctly?

Comment: @Asad Mahmood "when I try to do _it_"??  _it_ is unclear.

Comment: @Asad Mahmood What is unclear is your use of `fgets()`.  An example of your the code that uses `fgets()` would be helpful.

Comment: Instead of the `scanf(" %c", &mar); ` I tried to do it with `fgets(mar, 1, stdin);` When I compile it, it says "warning: passing argument 1 of âfgetsâ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]" , I wrote it then like this :`fgets(mar, 1, stdin);` and no errors were found, however when I compile and run the program and I get to the point where it asks if the female is married, it goes to the else statement and prints Unexpected input char: '' code:0.

Comment: @Asad Mahmood `fgets(mar, 1, stdin)` will not work.  1) first argument nneds to be a `char *`, not `char`.  2) `fgets()` wants to read a line of data and form a string, that takes at least an `char s[3]`.  3) `fgets()` does not code well with `scanf()`.  4) Unfortunately, the idea of using `fgets()` vs. `scanf()` involves removing all `scant()`.  Suggest you do that on your next assignment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88928/discussion-between-asad-mahmood-and-chux).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `scanf`. It does not remove the new-line character from the input buffer, so the first thing `getchar` reads is the `\n`-char.

To solve this you can, for instance add a `getchar` call before, so the character gets removed from the buffer and the next `getchar` reads your input. Like this:

```
...
scanf("%d", &age);
...
getchar();
mar = getchar();
...
```

Comment: or maybe he should just cease using `scanf()` altogether instead of trying to hack around its horrible behavior. OP wants to read one piece of data by line; therefore he should use `fgets()`. Using `fgets()` is also safer as it eliminates buffer overflow errors.